# Adding newsletter checkbox to Magento (1.4.1.1) one page checkout

Tags: php, magento

I've taken over an old project from a developer that just left and I could use some help just getting this done.

**What I'm trying to do:**

Magento (1.4.1.1) with one page checkout, I need to add a newsletter subscribe checkbox that if it is checked will subscribe the customer guest, registered or otherwise to the newsletter.

**What I've done:**

I've got a checkbox in the billing stage and I have got got a module that works by observing the event `checkout_type_onepage_save_order` and from that I subscribe the customer like so:

```
public function list_subscribe(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
{
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
    $customer = $quote->getCustomer();

    if (($customer instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer))
    {
        Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribeCustomer($customer);
    }
    else
    {
        Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
    }
}
```

That works fine but it subscribes everybody that visits the checkout and I need to somehow check that the checkbox is ticked in the checkout process. This is the part that has got me confused. I'm very new to Magento and just need to get this done so hoping a nice person out there can help me lean how would I go about doing this apparently simple check for a ticked checkbox?

Many thanks in advance for any contributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extension work for your requirement, if you want to add module, here is the link http://www.emthemes.com/em-newsletter-optin.html
there are many extension for doing this and its free of cost

Comment: Thanks I took this plugin apart and seems to do what I need. Magento's get and set methods were throwing me off before.